# Facebook connect with sencha

Tags: javascript, facebook, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm building a website and a simple app for android and iOS with sencha and I want it to connect to facebook and post something.
I've read the information and tried to implement [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). 
It works on the website, when I tap a button the facebook login poped out, asking me to login and authorize the facebook app I created. after I authorize it and got an access token, I can post something to timeline from the web. 
However, when I tried to pack it into .apk and install it on my android device it didn't work.

Is it possible to use Facebook Javascript SDK with sencha touch after I pack it to .apk ? or should I be use another method ? 
I'm hoping that anybody could help me with that, and an example would be nice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been reading up on doing this, and am starting to be afraid you might need to compile the app not with Sencha Cmd but rather with something like PhoneGap and integrate Facebook through using PhoneGap plug ins. The standard web log in for Facebook requires a callback URL which you wouldn't have in a compiled app.

Answer (score 0):

Write a handler in sencha to call your site's oAuth service for authentication...
Use this authentication for your mobile app... I dont think the issue was due to .apk did you try the same thing in a mobile browser and see if it worked???

Comment: the website is working on browser. The mobile app is basically the website that packed into .apk with sencha touch / sencha architect. Have you create mobile app that connect to facebook with sencha? If yes, could you give an example of the code used for the FB connect part?

Answer (score 0):

The Watch List lets you share which movies you have seen and want to see with your friends on Facebook. 
https://github.com/senchalearn/Watchlist